# Why $\langle a,x\rangle = \langle b,x\rangle,\forall x\in X\implies a=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be (possibly infinite-dimensional) Hilbert space. How can we show that if $$\langle a,x\rangle = \langle b,x\rangle,\forall x\in X$$ then $a=b$?

Comment: Nonnegativty property of inner products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $x = a-b$, and use $\langle y,y\rangle = 0 \iff y = 0$.